# Suppose I have a real, symmetric matrix $S$. Can we say anything about the column space of $S + R$ where $R$ is of full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question is in the title. Given a real, symmetric matrix $S$ and a full rank matrix $R$, can we relate the column space of $S$ to the column space of $S + R$? For the purposes of this discussion, $R$ can be real symmetric as well.

Comment: In general, we can't. What kind of "relation" are you looking for between these spaces?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am dealing with a constraint of the form $col(S)\supset col(A)$ for some $A$ and I'm wondering whether $col(S) \supset col(A + pI)$ also holds, where $p$ is a positive number, $A$ is a positive semi-definite matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Thinking about it, I would guess not since $A + pI$ is positive definite i.e. it's column space is $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @mr It looks like you've answered your own question